# Canonic form of a quadric

Tags: matrices, geometry, bilinear-form, quadrics

I have a question, how can determine the canonic form of the quadric associated to $F$, where $F$ is a bilinear form $\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R $ that its associated matrice is 
$A=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&-1\\
0&-1&0\\
-1&0&0\\
\end{matrix}\right)$?

Another question, what is the base of $\Bbb R^3$ in whic the quadric is in canonic form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadratic form associated to $F$ is $x^TAx$ and since $A$ is symmetric by spectral theorem $A$ can be diagonalized by a basis of orthogonal eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ that is

$$M=[v_1\,v_2\,v_3] \implies x=My\quad M^{-1}=M^T$$

and then

$x^TAx=(My)^TA(My)=y^TM^TAMy=y^T(M^{-1}AM)y=y^TDy=\lambda_1y_1^2+\lambda_2y_2^2+\lambda_3y_3^2$

which is the canonical form.

Comment: It's difficult find eigenvectoe with this matrix

Comment: @RobertoDeLaFuente We don't need eigenvectros but only the eigenvalues. I wrote the full derivation to explain why it works!

Comment: Yeah but I need so the basis whic tue basis is in canonic form. What vectors form this basis? I think the eigenvectors! But are difficoult to calculate

Comment: @RobertoDeLaFuente Ah ok you need also that! They are not difficult to find out by $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.

Comment: @RobertoDeLaFuente You can also use that, but it should be useful to try to obtain the result by hands.

Comment: Try to do! Look: I have $-\lamba^2(\lamba-1)$

Comment: @RobertoDeLaFuente Take a look here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0,0,-1%7D,%7B0,-1,0%7D,%7B-1,0,0%7D%7D

Comment: @RobertoDeLaFuente Actually, it’s quite easy to find eigenvectors for this matrix by inspection: $(0,1,0)^T$ is obviously one, as is $(1,0,1)^T$. A third one can also be found by inspection, but since the matrix is symmetric, you can also generate one by finding a non-zero vector orthogonal to the first two.

Comment: I love you!!!!!

Comment: last thing.
Are u sure that $M^{-1} = M^T$?

Comment: Yes since we can find orthogonal eigenvectors!

Answer (score 1):

Find an orthonormal basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that each $v_k$ is an eigenvector of $A$. If the correcponding eigenvalues are $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, and $\lambda_3$, then the canonical form will be $$(X_1,X_2,X_3)\mapsto\lambda_1{X_1}^2+\lambda_2{X_2}^2+\lambda_3{X_3}^2.$$